# Deleting a substring

Tags: matlab, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that deletes an index of a cell array if it contains a specific string.

For example, if the input value for the function is `({'Hello how are you?', 'I'm fine thank you', 'Have a nice day!'}, 'you')`, only the string `'Have a nice day!'` would be returned.

This is what I have so far (it doesn't delete the index, just the instances where it occurs):

```
function d = take_out(v, s)
d = regexprep(v(:), s, '');
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function d = take_out(v, s)
    d = v(cellfun('isempty', regexp(v(:), s)));
end
```

`regexp(v(:), s)` returns, for each cell of `v`, a (possibly empty) vector with the integer indices of each occurrence of `s`. `cellfun('isempty', ...)` checks if those vectors are empty, and returns a logical index which is used to select the appropriate cells of `v`.

Comment: It's in a function though.

Comment: @user1543042 Do you mean the code format in comments? Put it within backticks

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case for `cellfun`, this applies a function to each element of a cell. The function applied is to see if the substring `'you'` is found in the cell. If it is not then it is transferred to `d`.

```
function d = take_out(v, s)
    d = v(cellfun(@(x) isempty(strfind(x, s)), v));
end
```

Comment: Conversion to cells and back to matrices was redundant here. Edited. Hope you don't mind.